# MySQL - transfer between two MySQL servers

Tags: php, mysql

Normally I am using sqlite DB for my cache purposes but queries etc. are not as good as mysql ones. So I want to rebuild my cache structure with MySQL based one.

My current cache structure with SqLite db:

```
main data srv -> get data and write it in to local sqLite db
```

I am iterating every piece of data comes from main data server query and write it in to locale sqLite db.

[image]

[image: construct]

[image: sqlite cache]

Here is my current way. I don't wanna use directly query to show my visitors, I have usually +50K visitors daily, as you know it will be very hard to MySQL database to keep it up, in addition, there are over +15 million rows in these tables.

What am I planning; I am going to create a local mysql database in my current web cluster, and transfer these selected data to this server and show them to my visitors through local mysql db.

What my question is:

**Is there any specific way to transfer query to query data? Or should I use same way, iterate everything through "for" and write em to local mysql db? What should I do or any ideas?**

Comment: It might be helpful to add your code as text instead of screenshots.

Comment: Sorry, It's just a bad habit between friends :)

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html) might be solution to your problem.